# Как сделать прозрачной для наведения/клика прозрачную область кнопки в Unity?

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть Image в Canvas'е. У Image спрайт. Спрайт - дуга с прозрачным фоном. На Image наложен компонент Button. 
Проблема: При наведении или нажатии на прозрачную область Image, спрайт меняет цвет, а мне нужно чтобы цвет менялся только когда наводишь или нажимаешь на сам спрайт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, тебя интересует [UI.Image-alphaHitTestMinimumThreshold](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image-alphaHitTestMinimumThreshold.html)

Если у тебя резкий переход -- юзай просто 0.5f значение.

Если у тебя плавный переход на картинке -- используй код кинутый далее. При помощи даного кода сможешь легко подобрать себе тот уровень "прозрачности" который тебе нужен на конкретно даной кнопке -- прямо из эдитора.

Ну а дальше будешь уже использовать тот скрипт по линке.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Image))]
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Image btn;

    public float HitMinimumThreshold = 0.5f;

    void Start()
    {
        btn = gameObject.GetComponent<Image>();
    }

    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (HitMinimumThreshold != btn.alphaHitTestMinimumThreshold)
        {
            btn.alphaHitTestMinimumThreshold = HitMinimumThreshold;
        }
    }

}
```

так же нужно зайти в настройки спрайта и поставить галочку "read/write". В некоторых случаях еще нужно поставить MeshType на FullRect.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не помогло, область с низу по прежнему реагирует на наведение и нажатие, а сам спрайт наоборот перестал.

Comment: проапдейтил ответ.

Comment: Да, тут я галочку ставил сразу, проблема все та же

Comment: создай новый проэкт и попробуй на пустом проэкте повторить написанное мной. Я проверил и у меня работает. Если не работает у тебя - ты что-то пропустил.

Comment: Даже в новом проекте не работает. Я использую вот этот спрайт https://yadi.sk/i/Tb65AI28OZ1-Qg

Comment: у меня получилось добится нужного эфекта и с твоей текстурой. Подправив мештайп на фуллРект, как на прикрепленной картинке в моем ответе